# Explaining a Slick MySQL query with Explan

Tags: scala, slick

We have a complex select query which is not hitting the indexes as we are expecting and we would like to perform an explain. At the moment, we are not able to do so because:

- The query contains somewhere in the middle a `x2.49 in (_,_)` when printing as string `query.result.statements.head`.
- The names of the columns are unreadable

How can we obtain a sanely readable sql with already interpolated statements in slick?

Comment: If you want readable code in Slick Query. You can read this one https://medium.com/@kennajenifer1234/scala-tutorial-create-crud-with-slick-and-mysql-1b0a5092899f because it's implementation is good. :)

Comment: Have you tried logging slow queries not using indexes to file with `set global log_queries_not_using_indexes = 'ON'` and `set global slow_query_log_file ='/path/to/slow-query.log';` ? You'd be able to log all queries to log file.